# php array and mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying SwiftMailer to fetch the email addresses to an `array()` I have the original example and I know what I want to put in it but I can't see the forest from the trees... any one out there with proper eyes please:

```
// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);

// Send the message
$failedRecipients = array();
$numSent = 0;
```

Here is where I am struggling:

```
 foreach($groups as $value)
    { 
             echo "<h3>".$value."</h3>"; //this is working

    // get the email groups
    $sql="SELECT * FROM emails WHERE sendesstat=1 AND deleted=0 AND classhoz=\"".$value."\"";
    $query=mysql_query($sql);

    // fetch the emails from the group
    while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                  $emil="'".$data["email"]."' => '".$data["firstname"]." ".$data["surname"]."'";
                  echo $emil;
```

this `echo` is working but I can't put in the `$to[]` array... (sorry) and this is how it should appear:

```
$to = array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name');
```

the issue is the `given name  => 'A name'` I am being sick and I can't find the syntax !!!

```
                  $to[ ]= $emil;            
                }
    }

foreach ($to as $address => $name)
{
  if (is_int($address)) {
   $message->setTo($name);
  } else {
   $message->setTo(array($address => $name));
}

 $numSent += $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
}

printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);
```

please please everything else is working now only this bit is missing. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the `$to` array the wrong way.

Use this to add an item on the array

```
$to[$data["email"]] = $data["firstname"]." ".$data["surname"];
//  ^ Index           ^ Value
```

Later On, when you use `foreach` loop it will well differentiated into $address and $name, just the way you are doing.

```
foreach ($to as $address => $name) {
    echo $address;
    echo $name; 
}
```

Comment: thanks very much I am going to put in my code :)))) thanks a lot again